# Rich Text Editor : Display MathJax

Tags: javascript, mathjax

Parent doc uses MathJax to display mathematics. To display the maths in Rich text editors which uses iframe, could any one suggest a good and simple approach? I am now left with the following

a. to load the MathJax again in iframe.
Since the browser caches the js and css, this may not create additional overhead.

b. get all the scripts and css using js and reattach to the editor

c. or use rich text editor which uses div instead iframe.